# MOD command calling functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two functions, which are working fine. I want to use the MOD  or decode command to call the functions with different options but I can't seem to get the code below to work.

Below is my test CASE. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS.FF';

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp(
      p_from      IN TIMESTAMP,
      p_to        IN TIMESTAMP,
      p_fraction  IN VARCHAR2   DEFAULT 'Y'
    ) RETURN TIMESTAMP
   IS
      return_val_y TIMESTAMP     := p_from + dbms_random.value () * (p_to - p_from + INTERVAL '1' DAY);
      return_val_n TIMESTAMP (0) := return_val_y;
 BEGIN
      RETURN  CASE
                    WHEN UPPER (SUBSTR (p_fraction, 1, 1)) = 'Y'
          THEN return_val_y
          ELSE return_val_N
          END;
END random_timestamp;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_interval(
  p_min      IN NUMBER,
  p_max      IN NUMBER,
  p_duration IN VARCHAR2,
  p_fraction  IN VARCHAR2   DEFAULT 'Y'
) RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
IS
      return_val_y   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND   := NUMTODSINTERVAL(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(p_min, p_max), p_duration);

   return_val_n   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND   :=
( EXTRACT(DAY FROM return_val_y) * 24 * 60 * 60
         + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM return_val_y) * 60 * 60
         + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM return_val_y) * 60
         + FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM return_val_y))
         ) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
BEGIN
      RETURN  CASE
                    WHEN UPPER (SUBSTR (p_fraction, 1, 1)) = 'Y'
          THEN return_val_y
          ELSE return_val_N
       END;
 END random_interval;
/

/* can't get this to work */

SELECT
    CASE MOD(LEVEL, 2)
     WHEN 0
     THEN   
         random_timestamp(TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00', 'Y') as ts,
         random_interval(1, 10, 'HOUR', 'Y') as invr
     ELSE 
         random_timestamp(TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00', 'N') as ts,
         random_interval(1, 10, 'HOUR', 'N') as invr
     END
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` expression returns a single expression; not multiple expressions. If you want multiple expressions then move the `CASE` from wrapping both of them (which is wrong) to inside each of the function calls:

```sql
SELECT random_timestamp(
         TIMESTAMP '2022-04-01 00:00:00',
         TIMESTAMP '2022-04-30 00:00:00',
         CASE MOD(LEVEL, 2) WHEN 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) as ts,
       random_interval(
         1,
         10,
         'HOUR',
         CASE MOD(LEVEL, 2) WHEN 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
       ) as invr
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 10;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4jVfej7P)